# AWS API Gateway test

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-serverless

I am using AWS Educate account, I have deployed Serverless with api gateway. When I run the following

`apig-test --username='admin@example.com' --password='Passw0rd!' --user-pool-id='*****' --app-client-id='******' --cognito-region='us-east-1' --identity-pool-id='*****' --invoke-url='https://6mizip1zs8.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/' --api-gateway-region='us-east-1' --path-template='notes' --methos='POST' --body='{"content":"hello world","attachment":"hellp.jpg"}'`

I also tried to remove the slash after dev in `invoke-url` and add it in `path-template` but it doesn't change anything.

I receive the following error.

````
  status: 403,
  statusText: 'Forbidden',
  data: '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">\n' +
    '<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">\n' +
    '<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>\n' +
    '</HEAD><BODY>\n' +
    '<H1>403 ERROR</H1>\n' +
    '<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>\n' +
    '<HR noshade size="1px">\n' +
    'Bad request.\n' +
    "We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.\n" +
    '<BR clear="all">\n' +
    'If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.\n' +
    '<BR clear="all">\n' +
    '<HR noshade size="1px">\n' +
    '<PRE>\n' +
    'Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)\n' +
    'Request ID: Twl3TjhrKw2DTu9dEo0Rd1xQfILId5w_Mpa-tAa1s55dlo0uJWoMZQ==\n' +
    '</PRE>\n' +
    '<ADDRESS>\n' +
    '</ADDRESS>\n' +
    '</BODY></HTML>'
}```
````

Comment: Does api work without cognito? AWS educate accounts are super limited. Maybe you have no permissions for something there?

Comment: Cognito is available, because I have created a test user